# How to identify outliers with several grouping

Tags: r, excel, outliers, iqr

I am trying identify outliers from my data set from specific `relabs` column, but I need to calculate them in `Control` column with values 1 and 2 separately where `conc` column equals "NK" also grouping by `Treatment`.

Data set with reprex (should have 40 outliers, checked manually):

```
df <- wrapr::build_frame(
   "ID"  , "Treatment", "conc"   , "relabs", "Control" |
     1   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.9161  , 0         |
     2   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.8023  , 0         |
     3   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.7189  , 0         |
     4   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.7234  , 0         |
     5   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.6265  , 0         |
     6   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.6237  , 0         |
     7   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.6859  , 0         |
     8   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.8011  , 0         |
     9   , "A"        , "10 µM"  , 1.115   , 0         |
     10  , "A"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8961  , 0         |
     11  , "A"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7925  , 0         |
     12  , "A"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7006  , 0         |
     13  , "A"        , "10 µM"  , 0.6719  , 0         |
     14  , "A"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7363  , 0         |
     15  , "A"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8165  , 0         |
     16  , "A"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8958  , 0         |
     17  , "A"        , "1 µM"   , 1.168   , 0         |
     18  , "A"        , "1 µM"   , 1.066   , 0         |
     19  , "A"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8298  , 0         |
     20  , "A"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9315  , 0         |
     21  , "A"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8067  , 0         |
     22  , "A"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9296  , 0         |
     23  , "A"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8462  , 0         |
     24  , "A"        , "1 µM"   , 1.133   , 0         |
     25  , "A"        , "NK"     , 1.216   , 1         |
     26  , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.9856  , 1         |
     27  , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.8862  , 1         |
     28  , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.9599  , 1         |
     29  , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.8789  , 1         |
     30  , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.9304  , 1         |
     31  , "A"        , "NK"     , 1.057   , 1         |
     32  , "A"        , "NK"     , 1.086   , 1         |
     33  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 0.9173  , 0         |
     34  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 0.7754  , 0         |
     35  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 0.575   , 0         |
     36  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 0.6619  , 0         |
     37  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 0.5609  , 0         |
     38  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 0.5786  , 0         |
     39  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 0.6024  , 0         |
     40  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 0.889   , 0         |
     41  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.8515  , 0         |
     42  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.6961  , 0         |
     43  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.6754  , 0         |
     44  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.6816  , 0         |
     45  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.7234  , 0         |
     46  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.6961  , 0         |
     47  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.609   , 0         |
     48  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.7092  , 0         |
     49  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 0.9482  , 0         |
     50  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8245  , 0         |
     51  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8456  , 0         |
     52  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8181  , 0         |
     53  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7784  , 0         |
     54  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7393  , 0         |
     55  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8035  , 0         |
     56  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8296  , 0         |
     57  , "B"        , "1 µM"   , 1.237   , 0         |
     58  , "B"        , "1 µM"   , 1.081   , 0         |
     59  , "B"        , "1 µM"   , 0.987   , 0         |
     60  , "B"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8797  , 0         |
     61  , "B"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8077  , 0         |
     62  , "B"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8874  , 0         |
     63  , "B"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8942  , 0         |
     64  , "B"        , "1 µM"   , 1.157   , 0         |
     65  , "B"        , "NK"     , 1.216   , 1         |
     66  , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.9856  , 1         |
     67  , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.8862  , 1         |
     68  , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.9599  , 1         |
     69  , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.8789  , 1         |
     70  , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.9304  , 1         |
     71  , "B"        , "NK"     , 1.057   , 1         |
     72  , "B"        , "NK"     , 1.086   , 1         |
     73  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 0.9173  , 0         |
     74  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 0.7754  , 0         |
     75  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 0.575   , 0         |
     76  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 0.6619  , 0         |
     77  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 0.5609  , 0         |
     78  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 0.5786  , 0         |
     79  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 0.6024  , 0         |
     80  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 0.889   , 0         |
     81  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 0.8144  , 0         |
     82  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 0.7734  , 0         |
     83  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 0.8364  , 0         |
     84  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 0.613   , 0         |
     85  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 0.6863  , 0         |
     86  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 0.5953  , 0         |
     87  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 0.5552  , 0         |
     88  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 0.9572  , 0         |
     89  , "C"        , "10 µM"  , 1.256   , 0         |
     90  , "C"        , "10 µM"  , 1.035   , 0         |
     91  , "C"        , "10 µM"  , 0.9852  , 0         |
     92  , "C"        , "10 µM"  , 0.9186  , 0         |
     93  , "C"        , "10 µM"  , 0.907   , 0         |
     94  , "C"        , "10 µM"  , 0.9979  , 0         |
     95  , "C"        , "10 µM"  , 1.075   , 0         |
     96  , "C"        , "10 µM"  , 1.144   , 0         |
     97  , "C"        , "1 µM"   , 1.218   , 0         |
     98  , "C"        , "1 µM"   , 1.078   , 0         |
     99  , "C"        , "1 µM"   , 0.7224  , 0         |
     100 , "C"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9967  , 0         |
     101 , "C"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9748  , 0         |
     102 , "C"        , "1 µM"   , 0.6157  , 0         |
     103 , "C"        , "1 µM"   , 0.7437  , 0         |
     104 , "C"        , "1 µM"   , 1.191   , 0         |
     105 , "C"        , "NK"     , 1.317   , 1         |
     106 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.9297  , 1         |
     107 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.9184  , 1         |
     108 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.8788  , 1         |
     109 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.8719  , 1         |
     110 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.9015  , 1         |
     111 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.9266  , 1         |
     112 , "C"        , "NK"     , 1.256   , 1         |
     113 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 0.9173  , 0         |
     114 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 0.7754  , 0         |
     115 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 0.575   , 0         |
     116 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 0.6619  , 0         |
     117 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 0.5609  , 0         |
     118 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 0.5786  , 0         |
     119 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 0.6024  , 0         |
     120 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 0.889   , 0         |
     121 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.7008  , 0         |
     122 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.7397  , 0         |
     123 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.6957  , 0         |
     124 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.5245  , 0         |
     125 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.5118  , 0         |
     126 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.5568  , 0         |
     127 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.7559  , 0         |
     128 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.8191  , 0         |
     129 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 1.056   , 0         |
     130 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8304  , 0         |
     131 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8152  , 0         |
     132 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 0.709   , 0         |
     133 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7035  , 0         |
     134 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 0.6735  , 0         |
     135 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7893  , 0         |
     136 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 0.9783  , 0         |
     137 , "D"        , "1 µM"   , 1.294   , 0         |
     138 , "D"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9011  , 0         |
     139 , "D"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9489  , 0         |
     140 , "D"        , "1 µM"   , 0.7918  , 0         |
     141 , "D"        , "1 µM"   , 0.7772  , 0         |
     142 , "D"        , "1 µM"   , 0.759   , 0         |
     143 , "D"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8787  , 0         |
     144 , "D"        , "1 µM"   , 1.132   , 0         |
     145 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 0.9173  , 0         |
     146 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 0.7754  , 0         |
     147 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 0.575   , 0         |
     148 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 0.6619  , 0         |
     149 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 0.5609  , 0         |
     150 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 0.5786  , 0         |
     151 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 0.6024  , 0         |
     152 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 0.889   , 0         |
     153 , "D"        , "NK"     , 1.317   , 1         |
     154 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.9297  , 1         |
     155 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.9184  , 1         |
     156 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.8788  , 1         |
     157 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.8719  , 1         |
     158 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.9015  , 1         |
     159 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.9266  , 1         |
     160 , "D"        , "NK"     , 1.256   , 1         |
     161 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 0.9406  , 0         |
     162 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 0.7404  , 0         |
     163 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 0.7166  , 0         |
     164 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 0.5353  , 0         |
     165 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 0.6104  , 0         |
     166 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 0.555   , 0         |
     167 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 0.6529  , 0         |
     168 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 0.8834  , 0         |
     169 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 0.9397  , 0         |
     170 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8172  , 0         |
     171 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7854  , 0         |
     172 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8047  , 0         |
     173 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7185  , 0         |
     174 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7277  , 0         |
     175 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 0.852   , 0         |
     176 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 0.9809  , 0         |
     177 , "E"        , "1 µM"   , 1.295   , 0         |
     178 , "E"        , "1 µM"   , 1.138   , 0         |
     179 , "E"        , "1 µM"   , 0.86    , 0         |
     180 , "E"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9272  , 0         |
     181 , "E"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8434  , 0         |
     182 , "E"        , "1 µM"   , 0.92    , 0         |
     183 , "E"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8568  , 0         |
     184 , "E"        , "1 µM"   , 1.184   , 0         |
     185 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 0.9173  , 0         |
     186 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 0.7754  , 0         |
     187 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 0.575   , 0         |
     188 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 0.6619  , 0         |
     189 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 0.5609  , 0         |
     190 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 0.5786  , 0         |
     191 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 0.6024  , 0         |
     192 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 0.889   , 0         |
     193 , "E"        , "NK"     , 1.317   , 1         |
     194 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.9297  , 1         |
     195 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.9184  , 1         |
     196 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.8788  , 1         |
     197 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.8719  , 1         |
     198 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.9015  , 1         |
     199 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.9266  , 1         |
     200 , "E"        , "NK"     , 1.256   , 1         |
     201 , "A"        , "NK"     , 1.317   , 2         |
     202 , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.9297  , 2         |
     203 , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.9184  , 2         |
     204 , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.8788  , 2         |
     205 , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.8719  , 2         |
     206 , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.9015  , 2         |
     207 , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.9266  , 2         |
     208 , "A"        , "NK"     , 1.256   , 2         |
     209 , "B"        , "NK"     , 1.317   , 2         |
     210 , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.9297  , 2         |
     211 , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.9184  , 2         |
     212 , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.8788  , 2         |
     213 , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.8719  , 2         |
     214 , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.9015  , 2         |
     215 , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.9266  , 2         |
     216 , "B"        , "NK"     , 1.256   , 2         |
     217 , "C"        , "NK"     , 1.216   , 2         |
     218 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.9856  , 2         |
     219 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.8862  , 2         |
     220 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.9599  , 2         |
     221 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.8789  , 2         |
     222 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.9304  , 2         |
     223 , "C"        , "NK"     , 1.057   , 2         |
     224 , "C"        , "NK"     , 1.086   , 2         |
     225 , "D"        , "NK"     , 1.216   , 2         |
     226 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.9856  , 2         |
     227 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.8862  , 2         |
     228 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.9599  , 2         |
     229 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.8789  , 2         |
     230 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.9304  , 2         |
     231 , "D"        , "NK"     , 1.057   , 2         |
     232 , "D"        , "NK"     , 1.086   , 2         |
     233 , "E"        , "NK"     , 1.216   , 2         |
     234 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.9856  , 2         |
     235 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.8862  , 2         |
     236 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.9599  , 2         |
     237 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.8789  , 2         |
     238 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.9304  , 2         |
     239 , "E"        , "NK"     , 1.057   , 2         |
     240 , "E"        , "NK"     , 1.086   , 2         )
```

The data set I should get:

```
df <- wrapr::build_frame(
   "ID"  , "Treatment", "conc"   , "relabs" |
     1   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.9869   |
     2   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.8644   |
     3   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.7745   |
     4   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.7793   |
     5   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.675    |
     6   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.6719   |
     7   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.739    |
     8   , "A"        , "100 µM" , 0.8631   |
     9   , "A"        , "10 µM"  , 0.9654   |
     10  , "A"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8538   |
     11  , "A"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7548   |
     12  , "A"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7239   |
     13  , "A"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7933   |
     14  , "A"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8797   |
     15  , "A"        , "10 µM"  , 0.9651   |
     16  , "A"        , "1 µM"   , 0.894    |
     17  , "A"        , "1 µM"   , 1.004    |
     18  , "A"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8691   |
     19  , "A"        , "1 µM"   , 1.002    |
     20  , "A"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9117   |
     21  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 1.014    |
     22  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 0.8573   |
     23  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 0.6358   |
     24  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 0.7318   |
     25  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 0.6201   |
     26  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 0.6397   |
     27  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 0.666    |
     28  , "A"        , "10 µM X", 0.9829   |
     29  , "A"        , "NK"     , 1.062    |
     30  , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.9548   |
     31  , "A"        , "NK"     , 1.034    |
     32  , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.9469   |
     33  , "A"        , "NK"     , 1.002    |
     34  , "A"        , "NK"     , 1.028    |
     35  , "A"        , "NK"     , 1.015    |
     36  , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.9716   |
     37  , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.964    |
     38  , "A"        , "NK"     , 0.9967   |
     39  , "A"        , "NK"     , 1.024    |
     40  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.9174   |
     41  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.75     |
     42  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.7277   |
     43  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.7344   |
     44  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.7794   |
     45  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.7499   |
     46  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.6561   |
     47  , "B"        , "100 µM" , 0.7641   |
     48  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 1.022    |
     49  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8883   |
     50  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 0.911    |
     51  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8814   |
     52  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8387   |
     53  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7965   |
     54  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8656   |
     55  , "B"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8938   |
     56  , "B"        , "1 µM"   , 1.063    |
     57  , "B"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9478   |
     58  , "B"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8702   |
     59  , "B"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9561   |
     60  , "B"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9634   |
     61  , "B"        , "NK"     , 1.062    |
     62  , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.9548   |
     63  , "B"        , "NK"     , 1.034    |
     64  , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.9469   |
     65  , "B"        , "NK"     , 1.002    |
     66  , "B"        , "NK"     , 1.028    |
     67  , "B"        , "NK"     , 1.015    |
     68  , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.9716   |
     69  , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.964    |
     70  , "B"        , "NK"     , 0.9967   |
     71  , "B"        , "NK"     , 1.024    |
     72  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 1.014    |
     73  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 0.8573   |
     74  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 0.6358   |
     75  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 0.7318   |
     76  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 0.6201   |
     77  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 0.6397   |
     78  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 0.666    |
     79  , "B"        , "10 µM X", 0.9829   |
     80  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 0.9005   |
     81  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 0.8551   |
     82  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 0.9248   |
     83  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 0.6778   |
     84  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 0.7588   |
     85  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 0.6582   |
     86  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 0.6138   |
     87  , "C"        , "100 µM" , 1.058    |
     88  , "C"        , "10 µM"  , 1.144    |
     89  , "C"        , "10 µM"  , 1.089    |
     90  , "C"        , "10 µM"  , 1.016    |
     91  , "C"        , "10 µM"  , 1.003    |
     92  , "C"        , "10 µM"  , 1.103    |
     93  , "C"        , "10 µM"  , 1.188    |
     94  , "C"        , "1 µM"   , 1.192    |
     95  , "C"        , "1 µM"   , 0.7987   |
     96  , "C"        , "1 µM"   , 1.102    |
     97  , "C"        , "1 µM"   , 1.078    |
     98  , "C"        , "1 µM"   , 0.6808   |
     99  , "C"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8223   |
     100 , "C"        , "NK"     , 1.028    |
     101 , "C"        , "NK"     , 1.015    |
     102 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.9716   |
     103 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.964    |
     104 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.9967   |
     105 , "C"        , "NK"     , 1.024    |
     106 , "C"        , "NK"     , 1.062    |
     107 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.9548   |
     108 , "C"        , "NK"     , 1.034    |
     109 , "C"        , "NK"     , 0.9469   |
     110 , "C"        , "NK"     , 1.002    |
     111 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 1.014    |
     112 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 0.8573   |
     113 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 0.6358   |
     114 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 0.7318   |
     115 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 0.6201   |
     116 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 0.6397   |
     117 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 0.666    |
     118 , "C"        , "10 µM X", 0.9829   |
     119 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.7748   |
     120 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.8178   |
     121 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.7692   |
     122 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.5798   |
     123 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.5658   |
     124 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.6157   |
     125 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.8357   |
     126 , "D"        , "100 µM" , 0.9056   |
     127 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 1.168    |
     128 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 0.9181   |
     129 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 0.9013   |
     130 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7839   |
     131 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7778   |
     132 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7447   |
     133 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8727   |
     134 , "D"        , "10 µM"  , 1.082    |
     135 , "D"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9963   |
     136 , "D"        , "1 µM"   , 1.049    |
     137 , "D"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8755   |
     138 , "D"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8593   |
     139 , "D"        , "1 µM"   , 0.8392   |
     140 , "D"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9715   |
     141 , "D"        , "1 µM"   , 1.251    |
     142 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 1.014    |
     143 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 0.8573   |
     144 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 0.6358   |
     145 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 0.7318   |
     146 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 0.6201   |
     147 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 0.6397   |
     148 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 0.666    |
     149 , "D"        , "10 µM X", 0.9829   |
     150 , "D"        , "NK"     , 1.028    |
     151 , "D"        , "NK"     , 1.015    |
     152 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.9716   |
     153 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.964    |
     154 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.9967   |
     155 , "D"        , "NK"     , 1.024    |
     156 , "D"        , "NK"     , 1.062    |
     157 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.9548   |
     158 , "D"        , "NK"     , 1.034    |
     159 , "D"        , "NK"     , 0.9469   |
     160 , "D"        , "NK"     , 1.002    |
     161 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 1.04     |
     162 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 0.8186   |
     163 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 0.7923   |
     164 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 0.5918   |
     165 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 0.6749   |
     166 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 0.6136   |
     167 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 0.7218   |
     168 , "E"        , "100 µM" , 0.9768   |
     169 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 1.039    |
     170 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 0.9035   |
     171 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8684   |
     172 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8898   |
     173 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 0.7944   |
     174 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 0.8046   |
     175 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 0.942    |
     176 , "E"        , "10 µM"  , 1.085    |
     177 , "E"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9508   |
     178 , "E"        , "1 µM"   , 1.025    |
     179 , "E"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9325   |
     180 , "E"        , "1 µM"   , 1.017    |
     181 , "E"        , "1 µM"   , 0.9473   |
     182 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 1.014    |
     183 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 0.8573   |
     184 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 0.6358   |
     185 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 0.7318   |
     186 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 0.6201   |
     187 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 0.6397   |
     188 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 0.666    |
     189 , "E"        , "10 µM X", 0.9829   |
     190 , "E"        , "NK"     , 1.028    |
     191 , "E"        , "NK"     , 1.015    |
     192 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.9716   |
     193 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.964    |
     194 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.9967   |
     195 , "E"        , "NK"     , 1.024    |
     196 , "E"        , "NK"     , 1.062    |
     197 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.9548   |
     198 , "E"        , "NK"     , 1.034    |
     199 , "E"        , "NK"     , 0.9469   |
     200 , "E"        , "NK"     , 1.002    )
```

I used function identify_outliers by `Treatment` and `conc` and it works well, but I need this function as well to calculate outliers from my data set from `conc` "NK" and `Control` "1" and "2" separately, not combined, and then exclude all outliers by `anti_join`.

My current code, which does not separately calculate outliers from "NK" with "1" and "2". `Identify_outliers` comes from rstatix.

```
df_outliers <-
df %>% 
  group_by(Treatment, conc) %>% 
  identify_outliers("relabs") 

df_outliers
```

I exclude outliers by `anti_join`:

```
df_wo_outliers <- 
  df %>% 
  anti_join(df_outliers, by = "ID") %>% 
  view()
```

I have a lot of data so I don't want to do it manually if I can figure out how to do it with R.

Is there a way to calculate outliers grouping by `Treatment` and `conc`, as well as by separately calculating it if `Treatment` equals "NK" and Control is "1" and "2"?

Manual outlier calculation in excel:

[image: Excel_1]
[image: Excel_2]

Comment: Where does the `identify_outliers` function come from? It probably doesn't understand dplyr grouping attributes. You might have to use something like `group_map` instead.

Comment: Function is from rstatix. I'll try looking into group_map and see what I can do.

Comment: Does your sample data have any outliers? It doesn't seem helpful for testing. Also the images of data are not helpful either. We need something we can copy/paste into R for testing.

Comment: I could give my full data, but I'm not sure how to copy it and post here from excel. Is there a fast way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

** update **

If we use your `data` we find 9 outliers across all groups. I'm not sure how you identified 40. But the `group_by` approach is basically working.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)

data <- as_tibble(data) # for printing 

df_outliers <-
data %>% 
  group_by(Treatment, conc) %>%
  identify_outliers(relabs)

data %>% 
  anti_join(df_outliers, by = "ID") 
#> # A tibble: 231 x 5
#>       ID Treatment conc   relabs Control
#>    <dbl> <chr>     <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1     1 A         100 µM  0.916       0
#>  2     2 A         100 µM  0.802       0
#>  3     3 A         100 µM  0.719       0
#>  4     4 A         100 µM  0.723       0
#>  5     5 A         100 µM  0.626       0
#>  6     6 A         100 µM  0.624       0
#>  7     7 A         100 µM  0.686       0
#>  8     8 A         100 µM  0.801       0
#>  9     9 A         10 µM   1.12        0
#> 10    10 A         10 µM   0.896       0
#> # … with 221 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**old answer**

`rstatix::identify_outliers` works well with `dplyr::group_by` but to do so we first need outliers in our data. Below I changed the data to show how `identify_outliers` can work.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)

set.seed(1)
# setup:
# lets make the data set bigger
# and introduce some outliers in each group by making `relab` larger
df2 <- df %>%
  slice_sample(n = 10000,
               replace = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(Treatment, conc) %>% 
  mutate(row_id = row_number(),
         relabs = ifelse(row_id == 1, rnorm(1) * 100, relabs)) 

df_outliers <-
  df2 %>% 
  # df2 is already grouped so we don't need this here:
  # group_by(Treatment, conc) %>%
  identify_outliers(relabs)

df2 %>% 
  anti_join(df_outliers, by = c("ID", "row_id")) 

#> # A tibble: 9,990 x 6
#> # Groups:   Treatment, conc [10]
#>       ID Treatment conc  relabs Control row_id
#>    <dbl> <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <int>
#>  1     1 A         NK      0.91       1      2
#>  2     2 A         NK      0.83       2      3
#>  3    19 B         NK      0.98       1      2
#>  4     1 A         NK      0.91       1      4
#>  5    21 B         10X     0.66       0      2
#>  6    10 A         100     0.12       0      2
#>  7    14 B         NK      0.93       2      3
#>  8    10 A         100     0.12       0      3
#>  9     7 A         NK      0.73       1      5
#> 10    15 B         10X     0.62       0      3
#> # … with 9,980 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it. Also I've just posted some of my data with reprex, so it should have 40 outliers as I've checked manually

Comment: @Simona: See my updated answer. With your data I only find 9 outliers, when we apply `identify_outliers` by groups of `Treatment` and `conc`.

Comment: Thank you. I've also found 9 with identify_outliers, but it's not what I truly need. I want my code **to calculate outliers from NK when Control is 1 separately from NK when control is 2**, so it sums up to 40 for all treatment and concentration (i did it manually in excel). As I've showed in my last picture those NK groups for outliers should be calculated separately

Comment: @Simona: Please post the formula you use to calculate 'outliers'. My guess is that your formula and `identify_outliers` use different thresholds.

Comment: First I calculate Q1 and Q3 in excel for 8 same conc relabs with =QUARTILE. Then i calculate IQR by Q3-Q1. Then L bound: Q1-(1.5*IQR) and U bound: Q3+(1.5*IQR). With this I then use =OR(specific relabs<$L bound$,>specific relabs$U bound$) for all of the relabs in same conc and treatment checking all 88 relabs with it's L bound and U bound. This is the link for more clarity: https://www.howtogeek.com/400211/how-and-why-to-use-the-outliers-function-in-excel/

Comment: @Simona: It seems like the calculation is the same as in `identify_outliers`. Then it must depend on the grouping. If we use `group_by(Treatment, conc)` we will have `25` groups. How many different groups do you calculate the outliers for?

Comment: I calculate it for 30 groups in total, because NK (negative control) goes for all the `conc` groups - 6, since NK has two categories (`Control` 1 and 2) and `Treatment` is 5 categories